# android.os.networkonmainthreadexception inside a new Thread

Tags: android, multithreading

I am aware that you can't do network operations in the main thread, since Android 3.0. So, I made my call inside a new `Thread`:

```
button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        user=login.getText().toString();
        password=pass.getText().toString();
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("user", user));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("pass", password));
        Thread thread=new Thread(){
            public void run(){
                try {
                    // Throws exception here
                    response=CustomHttpClient.executeHttpPost(urlogin, params); 
                    response=response.replaceAll("\\s+","");

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                if(response.equals("ok")){

                    Intent home=new Intent(c, HomeActivity.class);
                    home.putExtra("username", user);
                    startActivity(home);
                    Toast toast=Toast.makeText(
                        c, getString(R.string.welcome), Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                    toast.show();
                }else{
                    if(response.equals("fallo")){
                        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                Toast toast=Toast.makeText(
                                    c, R.string.nologin, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                                toast.show();
                                login.setText("");
                                pass.setText("");
                            }
                        });
                    }else if(response.equals("nologin")){
                        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                Toast toast=Toast.makeText(
                                    c, R.string.nouser, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                                toast.show();
                                login.setText("");
                                pass.setText("");

                            }
                        });
                    }
                }
            }
        };
        thread.run();
    }
});
```

But, I receive that exception despite I'm **not** on main thread (or at least I think that...)

Answer (score 52, accepted):

using `run()` does not start a separate thread, it actually starts a runnable on the same thread that it was started on.

you need to use `start()` to start a new thread.

Comment: I had the same problem and couldnt figure out why I was getting this error too and that was the problem

Comment: Yes. I was the same. some break from Java development and even Threads happens to be a little confusing :)

Comment: Note that you still have to implement your code in the `run()` function. Network operations in `start()` cause this error too.

Answer (score 0):

These lines

```
Toast toast=Toast.makeText(c, getString(R.string.welcome), Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
toast.show();
```

need to be ran on the `UI Thread` as you are doing a couple times below it with `runOnUiThread()`. `Toast` is a `UI` element.

Comment: Yes, that is another error... but the call dont even left the phone because of the exception I say. Tried your solution and I keep getting the same Exception. Thanks for the answer, and for remembering me that :)

Comment: @tyczj You're right but I knew that was a problem and figured the OP was confused on the error. Didn't notice how the `Thread` was being started...good catch

Answer (score -2):

You can use this code

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9) {
    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = 
        new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
}
```

to avoid exception also for SDK > 9 you need to execute network operations on seperate thread other than UI or you can use [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html).

Comment: This is not the best, or even proper, way of handling this. Background `Thread` should be used like `AsyncTask` or the way the OP is with a couple changes

Comment: @Fustigador I know its a bad practice, i tried to provide you fastest way to avoid this exception.